# I want to get the Current Release Year (version) of a BIM360 Project, not a single file but BIM360 Project

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to fetch the Current Release Year (Version) of the BIM360 Project using an API or something else which does not require downloading the whole Project.

As there are more than 2000 BIM360 Projects it would be impossible to download each and get the information.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxoAG.png)

I've also marked in the image (This is the info i need).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.